# How can I guarantee that a process is completed in JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a `JSF` project. I use a bean called `uploadBean` which is `view scoped`. It takes some files from user and uploads them to the server then saves the files in a defined directory.

After the files saved in a directory, I want to carry out some operations on that uploaded files and that operations could take more then thirty seconds.

My question is what I should do to ensure these operations can continue to run even if the user closes the page or my scope enters destroy?

Note:
A user may leave from the page if he copmletes uploading his files but my operations on that files must start after his uploads completed and continue its own processes till that operations finish.

I'm eager to read your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend to do the file processing in an external component, not directly in your web application. This external component may be an EJB that's deployed in the same application server and which receives a JMS call from the web application (per file or per group of files, this depends on your specific requirements) and start processing each file on its own.

Comment: I wonder If I can call a static function? I don't want to enlarge creating another app and all these stuff in an app.

Comment: *I wonder If I can call a static function?* Don't wonder, try it first. If it doesn't work, come back here, edit your question and explain that such approach didn't work for your case. Also, this problem is unrelated to JSF at all.

Comment: I thought it is a bit related jsf life cycle.

Comment: No, this isn't related to JSF lifecycle. It's true that the processing of the files will be at the 5th phase but it will be the application server (JBoss/Wildfly, GlassFish or whatever you're using) which will decide if the executing thread should continue living or be stopped. Moving it into a `static` method won't change this behavior. The best bet is to move the file processing to an external thread. Creating such threads inside your web app is not recommendable.

Comment: The answer is *you can't*. If the user closes the browser page before the HTTP request is completed, there's not much you can do (maybe warn the user with a javascript popup). Like you've already been advised, don't run lengthy critical processes synchronously